# Multiple IF AND OR Nested Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I'm trying to create a project roadmap that will color itself.  Currently I am only able to get it to look at 1 set of dates, then use conditional formatting to create the color bar (Gantt chart).

So, here's what I'm trying to do:

- Look at the first set of dates, if empty,
- look at the 2nd set of dates, if empty,
- look at the 3rd set of dates
- Determine if the dates enter falls between 2 date ranges, if so... enter 1
- I'm using the "1" and conditional formatting to color the cell (gantt chart)

  1. First, look at N5, if empty look at L5.
      
      If not empty, `=IF(AND($J5<=AE$4,$K5>=AE$4),1,"")`  put a 1 if the date is in range
  2. When you look at L5 In #1, I want the following conditions:
      
      Look at L5, if empty, look at J5.
      
      If not empty, `=IF(AND($J5<=AE$4,$K5>=AE$4),1,"")`  same formula as above
  3. When you look at J5 in #2, I want the following conditions:
      
      If not empty, `=IF(AND($J5<=AE$4,$K5>=AE$4),1,"")`  same formula as above

Comment: You can place an image on a public server and post the link. Someone else can include the picture for you.

Comment: This currently does not make sense.  If all your conditions point to `the same formula as above` then you will never get different results

Comment: Is there any relation to the three columns of dates? IOW, could you just take the maximum date from the three columns? Which is more important?

Comment: Your *date range* is actually a single cell. Where is the second date to create the range?

Comment: What is in column M?

Comment: @jeeped

Thank you...  • I have 3 sets of dates (start and end dates)  • I want Excel to look at the 1st set >if empty >look at the 2nd set >if empty, look at the 3rd set.  •  Then take those dates and if the start & end falls within a certain range, enter 1, otherwise 0

Comment: I cannot have excel just look at the max date as project dates could have changed (moved up or down).   RE: Importance>>  the 3rd set of dates are more important than the 2nd set.  And the 2nd set is more important than the 1st.   •  Essentially, 3rd would override 2nd, and 2nd would override 1st.  But I need to see how project dates have evolved.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like this, add where i place the text your comparisons of date and there you are:

```
 =IF(B3="",IF(C3="","both EMPTY","B3 empty C3  with value"),IF(C3="","C3 empty B3 with value","both with value"))
```